# xamp code not working wamp server not working

Tags: php

php code work on xamp server but the same code  not work in wamp server.configfile show error here is my coding

```
<?php
if (strtoupper(substr(PHP_OS, 0, 3)) === 'WIN'){
    define("PATH_SEPARATOR", ";");
}else{
    define("PATH_SEPARATOR", ":");
}   
import_request_variables("gP");


define("WELCOME_ADMIN","<span class='adminwelcome'>Welcome to the <br>
    Administrative Console of </span><br><span class='adminlargetitle'>Recipe</span>");
define("SITE_NAME", "www.fff.com");//i am using xamp for php coding.its works  perfectly. but i am put that code to wamp server its showing error

define("SITE_HEADING", "fff");
define("TITLE", "food");
define('SITE_ROOT',  'http://localhost/fff/');
define('DIR_ROOT',   'C:/xampp/htdocs/fff/');   
?>
```

Comment: Define "not working". Do you receive any errors? If yes, which ones? What do you expect this script to do?

Answer (score 0):

use this code, the `PATH_SEPARATOR` is reserved variable, you can't reuse it for assignment.

```
if (strtoupper(substr(PHP_OS, 0, 3)) === 'WIN'){
   define("PATH_SEPARATOR1", ";");  //you can't use `PATH_SEPARATOR`
}else{
   define("PATH_SEPARATOR1", ":");
}
```